# Gunicorn: Not able to start It from remote server

Tags: python, gunicorn

I am trying to run gunicorn for an application but it's not able to run from any remote server or by any other tool. However, When I am trying to execute the script from bash by logging in into the server then its working fine. I have also tried supervisord but getting the same error. Is there anything which I am missing out?

```
ssh -t ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com << EOF
bash /home/ubuntu/code/xyz/gunicorn_start2
EOF
```

gunicorn_start2

```
#!/bin/sh
export PROJECT_ENV="dev"
exec /home/ubuntu/code/xyz xyz.wsgi:application --name xyz --workers 4 --user=ubuntu --timeout=3600  --debug --log-level debug --daemon
```

Comment: are you sure you run it with same user each time?

Comment: Yes, I am killing gunicorn process before running this script.

Answer (score 0):

Mohit, try this

```
ssh -T ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com <<'EOF'

PROJECT_ENV="dev"
exec /home/ubuntu/code/xyz xyz.wsgi:application --name xyz --workers 4 --user=ubuntu --timeout=3600  --debug --log-level debug --daemon

EOF
```

Comment: Its not helping. Even its not able to run the process.